# Collapsible feature not working in angular8

Tags: angular

Im trying to implement collapse in Angular8, but its not working

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" name="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

we can do `(click)="isCollapse=!isCollapse"`, but i want to use collapse in `foreach` **loop**.

Comment: Can you please post full code, with `ngFor` and `click`

Comment: Actually above peace of code also not working                                            <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#' + data.id">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="'#'+data.id" name="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) along side bootstrap and here is the example of [collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)

> As you posted your code in comment, there are some typos in your code
>
> This should be `[attr.data-target]="'#' + data.id"` ->
>   `[attr.data-target]="'#' + item.id"` as `item` is a current/each item.

So **full example** with `ng-bootstrap`

**You have to use unique variable for each item**

```
// .ts
data = [
    {
      isCollapsed: false
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: true
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: false
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: true
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: false
    },
  ];

//.html
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="item.isCollapsed = !item.isCollapsed">Toggle</button>
    </p>
    <div class="card" [ngbCollapse]="item.isCollapsed">
        <div class="card-body">
            You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-for-shabbir-g)